# Why emacs makes weird indents in arrays

Tags: indentation, web-mode, align

Often, emacs makes weird indentation in arrays: first line indented properly, but next lines are indented twice.

This behaviour found mostly in php (with web-mode):

```php
array(
    array( 'name' => 'Add', 'url' => '/add/', 'rules' => array() ),
        array( 'name' => 'List', 'url' => '/list/', 'rules' => array() ),
        array( 'name' => 'Sections', 'url' => '/section/', 'rules' => array() ),
)
```

But also found in typescript mode (also with web-mode):

```
[
  new NavItem('Home', '/'),
    new NavItem('About project', '/about-prj'),
    new NavItem('About', '/about'),
]
```

How to fix this behaviour?

Comment: If you don't use `web-mode`, can you reproduce the problem? AFAICT, all of these modes are third-party contibutions, so probably the best thing to do is post on issue on their github repos. If `web-mode` is the culprit, then start there. If `web-mode is innocent, then start with the other two.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue with `php-mode`, so the tag can be safely removed from this question. And, just in case, here's the link to [web-mode Issue tracker](https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/issues).